# Why App Links Assistant show SHA256 error

Tags: android, android-studio, deep-linking, sha

I'm trying to connect my app to my website, I'm try to do it in debug mode, and in my GitHub server at the moment, but it's not working. I'm getting SHA-256 error again and again.

**Here's what I tried in Android studio** https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IdnL.png

**Here's what I tried in the online generator tool**
https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaDnd.png

**Here's how I get the SHA-256** https://i.stack.imgur.com/igpxr.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There's no code
I go step by step with by this short video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpaByLW_ctw and all right except of when i'm try to generate the Digital Asset, that my result https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IdnL.png

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I am having the same issue.